# Client Certificate not running on Production

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, restsharp

I have configured a X509 Certificate using RestSharp on a C# Web application running on .NET Core 3.1. I am able to receive a 200 on all endpoints when on Development, however when published on IIS. The system is unresponsive.

Any guide on where I may be going wrong?

This is a sample of the code in question:

```
        var restClient = new RestClient("");

        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 9999;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (s, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

        X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\Users\xx\xxx.pfx", "");
        restClient.ClientCertificates = new X509CertificateCollection() { certificate };
        restClient.Proxy = new WebProxy();

        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

        request.Parameters.Clear();
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", string.Format("Bearer {0}", Get()));
        request.AddHeader("ClientID", "443E8BE7-3844-4555-898D-93F728B0BD50");
        request.AddParameter("mystuff", ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

I am testing my endpoints using Swagger

Comment: Are you doing many concurrent client requests? If yes, locking of the cert file can be an issue, reach client trying to open the very same file. Instead, make it a singleton so that you read once without possible locking.

Comment: @WiktorZychla The Requests are not concurrent.

Comment: Your code is unsafe. You're re-enabling unsafe TLS protocols while preventing the use of new protocols like TLS 1.3. Don't do that. .NET Core will use the most secure algorithm available by the OS by default

Comment: When you say the system is "unresponsive", what does that mean, exactly? Is it just hanging? Do you get a response at all? Does it time out?

Comment: @JuanR I am receiving a 404 on the same endpoint on production

Comment: @Nickson 404 != unresponsive. Two very different things.

Comment: Just a wild though. Might it be that IIS is not recognizing the client certificates?

Comment: @Nickson Are you sure you are hitting the right endpoint? (with the right protocol and port?)

Comment: @JuanR Yes. I am using Swagger API to test endpoints on both environments

Comment: @Nickson when you say you are using Swagger API to test endpoints, what exactly are you doing? Are you using Swagger Inspector?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244647/discussion-between-nickson-and-juanr).

Comment: Could you possibly improve your question to clarify what exact symptoms are? I also believe that 404 and unresponsive are not synonyms. Which basically mean that you give important details in comments under the question